# Can I set a database value to null in VB using a StringBuilder?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have an application that when I run an update statement, on a given condition a value must be set to null.

I am using `StringBuilder` to create my sql string and I can't a value to set to null. Given that I've used the `DBNull.Value` and it's inserting a blank string (`""`) into the database instead of *`null`* can you insert a null value into a database using a stringbuilder and an execute query statement?

Here is what I am using. I have tried just `.Append(DBNull.Value)` but a query won't execute like that because it doesn't put anything there so the query ends up like

`... , [lastRunProcessGUID] = where ...` (using `Nothing` results in the same thing)

```
With psSql
    .Append("update [connection string] ")
    .Append("set [Status] = ")
    .Append("'" & newStatus & "' ")

    If newStatus.Equals("0") Then
        .Append(", [lastRunProcessGUID] = ")
        .Append("'" & DBNull.Value & "'")
    End If

    .Append(" where [workItemID] = ")
    .Append("'" & workItemID & "' AND")
    .Append("' [StepLogID] = ")
    .Append("'" & stepLogID & "'")
End With
```

Comment: I could be dead wrong (hence leaving it as a comment), but I think replace `.Append("'" & DBNull.Value & "'")` with `.Append("NULL")` - no text delimiters - Just explicitly stating the value NULL.

Comment: **NO, you can't!** Well, you can, but only if you don't care if your program gets hacked. And for that matter, your existing non-null parameters are still going to get you hacked, probably sooner rather than later.

Comment: Be VERY careful of SQL injection, when building dynamic SQL like this.

Comment: Why do you say that, @JoelCoehoorn? Truly not sure how that could happen if all this were to happen on the back end?

Comment: @JohnBustos Where you think variables like newStatus get populated from? All data comes from the user at some point.

Comment: ... Ok, I got it... I was just curious about the NULL statement itself... Makes sense.

Comment: yes, this code is very vulnerable to injection.

Comment: the application is internal for the dev team so i'm not too worried about sql injection. but thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are building the SQL statement as a string just write the syntax as you would using Mgmt-Studio

```
if newStatus.Equals("0") Then
    .Append(", [lastRunProcessGUID] = NULL")
End If
```

`DbNull.Value` is more useful when performing logic when reading a value from the DB.

```
if ( rdr["col"] == DbNull.Value ) { ... }
```

I would change your code to use `Parameterized` SQL to prevent SQL Injection or use stored procedures instead of dynamic SQL generated from the application, if possible or appropriate.